# Randomized color with array modifier

Tags: materials, modifiers

I'm learning Blender, and I want to make keys for a keyboard with RBG lights incorporated inside them (final render will be an image, not an animation).

I created a low-poly key, with 2 material : 1 for base color, and a second one for the random color.
So here is what I did

[image: Material settings]

But now, i simply want to make an array to fill the keyboard. But the colors is not random at all, it stays the same.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

### Cycles

You can use parameter **[Random per Island](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html)**

*"A random value for each connected component (island) of the mesh. It is useful to add variations to meshes composed of separated units like tree leaves, wood planks, or curves of multiple splines."*

[image]

---

BTW For "rainbow" *ColorRamp* you can set just a two colors (Red-Blue) with **HSL** > **Clockwise**.
Or for your full ring - Red-Cyan-Red. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq40Z.jpg

Comment: Cool, didn't know about this one :).

Comment: .. @JachymMichal   Agreed! I instinctively thought it meant per UV usland, not per mesh island.. I couldn't imagine why Cycles needed this information.. still can't..

Comment: @RobinBetts I think its super usefull. I was looking for this feature quite a long time :) Shame it is just for a Cycles for now. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html

Answer (score 13):

### Eevee / Cycles

You can change the *array modifier* UV settings:

[image]

If the UV map of the base object is between 0 and 1, shifting them by 1 in the modifier allows to get a integer part in the nodes (using *"vector math/ceil"* node for instance). Then get a color with *"white noise texture"* (or in a colorramp).

Comment: @vklidu Hi. your link is "undefined".

Comment: @vklidu... ok, use "ceil" from "vector math", not from "math"! ; ) My bad... will edit my answer. Thanks to point that out.

Comment: @vklidu, no no, this is not your attention. My answer said "math" (not "vector math") before I edited it following your result.

Comment: Yes, but I could notice the violet header (or fact that UV is a vector input), but since nodes can be mixed often across logical hierarchy ... I was in my box :)

Comment: I tried to replace White Noise Texture with ColorRamp but I can't seem to make it work.  Mind pointing me to the right direction, please? Any hint would be very mush appreciated :D thanks in advance [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=MlxyrMR4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/MlxyrMR4/)

Comment: @Sophia, colorramp wants a factor between 0 and 1. So replace "ceil" by "floor" (to start at 0) and scale that by a factor (so that all above 1 is stretched back to one). For instance scaling by around 0.4 seems to work well in your case.

Comment: @Sophia in complement: only V (Y) is shifted in your array. You can also use "separate xyz" in order to take Y only. Then round (floor) and divide it to fit into 0-1.

Comment: thanks so much, lemon. I didn't realise to use floor. I got it working with floor followed by a map range. I also tried the separate xyz but I couldn't make it to work so I sticked with your first solution. Thanks again! that was very educational :)

Answer (score 3):

Without the modifiers applied, all the "keys" are still considered one object. However, as you can see from the image below, even with the modifiers applied, the end result is still one piece (therefore nothing to randomize).

[image: Array1]

The solution is (after applying the array modifier(s)) to select the whole mesh (all the keys) in edit mode, and separate by loose parts. This will make all the keys into separate objects, though, so you will want to finish any array modifications first.

[image: Separate]

Comment: And what do you do if you have about 5000 objects in your array? And what if afterwards you want to adjust the array?