# How to randomly assign color to objects in an array

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have this stack of 1610 bricks. The stack was built by starting from one brick, and then applying 3 consecutive **arrays** on it (3 dimensions).

I want each brick to be **randomly** assigned any of **4 fixed colors**, but the node I came up with (picture) only seems to assign a single color to the entire stack.

What did I do wrong, or what is an alternative way?

PS: I want to keep the Arrays (if afterward I want to adjust the distance between the bricks, or the dimensions of the bricks)

[image]

Comment: Using Cycles you also have a "random per island" (geometry node).

Comment: The Object Info > Random socket will only work with different objects, your object is arrayed but it is still one object. Geometry > Random Per Island will work if you use Cycle. For Eevee I don't know if it's possible without applying the modifier, but once done you can create instances of one unique brick then use Random...

Answer (score 5):

I was in *Eevee*, changed to *Cycles* and it worked. There was no need to apply the array modifiers, so they are still available.

[image]

Further reading: [Randomized color with array modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200469/randomized-color-with-array-modifier)

Comment: Consider that this site is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. Read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/why-is-saying-thanks-forbidden-here and also https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer